# strange script issue in Powershell

Tags: arrays, string, function, powershell

I am new to PowerShell, but not scripting.

Why does this script:

```
$usr = "john.doe"
$usrname = $usr -split ".", 0, "simplematch"
$fullname = upperInitial($usrname[0]) + upperInitial($usrname[1])
write-host "Hello $fullname"

function upperInitial($upperInitialString) {
  return $upperInitialString.substring(0, 1).toupper() + $upperInitialString.substring(1).tolower()
}
```

return me just 'Hello John' and not 'Hello John Doe'?

Comment: What was the issue you are facing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not treating the second call of the `upperInitial` function as a function, it's treating it as a paramter of the first call to the function I think.

Either of these work:

```
$fullname = "$(upperInitial($usrname[0])) $(upperInitial($usrname[1]))"
write-host "Hello $fullname"
```

The above uses the subexpression operator `$()` to execute the functions within a double quoted string.

```
$fullname = (upperInitial($usrname[0])) + ' ' + (upperInitial($usrname[1]))
write-host "Hello $fullname"
```

This one combines the result of the two functions as you had intended, although I also added a space character because otherwise it was JohnDoe.

Comment: Correct :-) This is a classic "why doesn't my C#-like syntax work in PowerShell" issue

Comment: There's also issues using parentheses with function calls.  The syntax for calling a function in PowerShell is `FunctionName $Arg1 $Arg2`, not `FunctionName($Arg1,$Arg2)`.  They work like a cmdlet, not like a C# function.  For a single argument function you probably won't have issues, but functions with multiple arguments will not work because parentheses have a different meaning in PowerShell.  It's best to avoid looking like the C# syntax completely.